# Problema con setSelectedItem en JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, poo, combobox

Tengo un problema para fijar en un combobox un objeto.
Os explico la situación.
Tengo un mysql una tabla con una serie de datos(tabla cliente), uno de esos datos es una clave externa a otra tabla(tabla ciudad).
En mi programa java creo un objeto con los datos del cliente, relleno un comboBox con la lista de los clientes, cuando eliges uno de estos cliente del combo, se recuperan los datos. La ciudad también se recupera, una vez recuperada quiero que esa ciudad se seleccione en el combo con la lista de todas las ciudad que hay.

Osea si el cliente 1 tiene la ciudad 2, cuando se recupere el cliente 1 en el combo de las ciudades tiene que aparecer la ciudad 2. Pero aqui esta el problema que se queda vacío.
Os pongo el código:

```
CiudadVO ciudad = new CiudadVO();
CiudadDAO ciudaddao = new CiudadDAO();
ciudad = ciudaddao.buscarCiudad(clienteModificado.getIdCiudad());
comboCiudad.setSelectedItem(ciudad);
```

Creo un objeto ciudad con el idciudad recuperado de la base de datos, esto lo hace bien e probado a imprimirlo y eso correcto, creo un objeto ciudad apartir de ese id, ahora quiero ponerlo en el combo con setSelectedItem y no funciona.
No se cual es el problema, si alguien sabe sería de mucha ayuda.

Gracias

Comment: Intenta acceder a algún atributo de tu clase `CiudadVO` , para setear el `SelectedItem`, por ejemplo al atributo nombre, `comboCiudad.setSelectedItem(ciudad.getNombre());` , **teniendo en cuenta que el valor a Seter esté como item en el Combo**

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo, sigue sin salir nada.

Comment: Tiene todas las ciudades cargadas. Por eso no entiendo que es lo que esta fallando. Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Te has asegurado de cargar al inicio el > Combobox comboCiudad? Y si es así te recomiendo que de la lista que hayas insertado en el comboBox, cojas la ciudad de ahí y hagas un Equal, claro para obtener la ciudad elegida de la lista tendrás que comparar esta primero ya sea por el nombre con la ciudad elejida por la persona.

Answer (score 1):

El método setSelectedItem() utiliza el método equals() para determinar cuál seleccionar. Por lo tanto, deberías haber definido este método en la clase CiudadVO. Me imagino que ese puede ser tu problema.

Por ejemplo, en la clase CiudadVO debe estar definido el método equals, quedando algo así:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return this.id == ((CiudadVO) other).id;
}
```